# Retrieving Data from AngularFire : "^5.0.0-rc0" to component's HTML file using service

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angularfire5

I'm trying to retrieve data from **Angularfire  : "^5.0.0-rc0"**  using a service, and want to return the result to the component using this service, and the component should print the result from firebase to html file.

I am facing issue due to async retrieval of data from firebase, although I am getting proper response in console but don't know how to get the data in my component's html file.

**Please note : `FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>;` won't work** in current version of angularfire, following are my files :

**trip-data.service.ts :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var firebase: any;
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Injectable()
export class TripDataService {

finalItems;
public data: Array<any> =[];
public myData: any[] =[];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {

    db.object('/').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
            this.finalItems = { ...action.payload.val() };
            return this.finalItems;
          }).subscribe(item => {
            console.log(item);
            this.myData = item;
            console.log(this.myData);
          }
          );
    }
}
```

**list.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TripDataService } from '../trip-data.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  providers: [TripDataService]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
trips;
      constructor(service: TripDataService) {
            // this.trips = service();
            this.trips = service.myData;
            console.log(this.trips);
       }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a different myData in the component. It gets reassigned when you receive the data in your service. Have a method in your service return an observable instead and subscribe to that in your component. Or better yet, use the async pipe in your template.

Comment: Can you show me how ? I am new to observable and subscribe functions and also how to use async in template ? It would be really helpful

Comment: Docs have a good example: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md

Comment: I like to do stuff like <div *ngIf="(item|async); let item">  Got {{ item.stuff }} here, async pipe handles subscribing and changeDetection triggering so I can use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush! </div>

Comment: services are really not needed unless you do some side effects with the data, as AF2 is so simple to use :)

Comment: But to your original code, you could move everything in the service 's constructor to a method getData. Then remove .subscribe out of it, and in the component you'd call this.service.getData().subscribe( data => this.data = data);

Comment: But if you subscribe yourself like that, remember to unsubscribe in component's ngOnDestroy. Async pipe handles that for you aswell so it's a carefree solution

Comment: I tried the above solutions you gave, but on moving subscribe code to component's constructor, it throws error that, "Property getData()  does not exist on type 'TripDataService' " Following is my code :

component file : 
`export class ListCompFirebasrComponent implements OnInit {
trips;
trip : any;
   constructor(service: TripDataService) {
    this.trips = service.getData().subscribe(item => {
     console.log(item);
    });
     console.log(this.trips);
    }
   ngOnInit() {

   }
}`

Comment: Glad to see you resolved it and seems you got what was perhaps the most important point in my long messy monologue lol - it's best practice to return an Observable from services and _never_ call subscribe in a service.ts.  =)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

export class ListCompFirebasrComponent implements OnInit { trips; trip : any; constructor(private service: TripDataService) { this.trips = this.service.getData().subscribe(item => { console.log(item); }); console.log(this.trips); } ngOnInit() { } }

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned earlier,that I wanted to post the response from firebase on my html page as soon as response was received, Thanks @toni for help. I solved it in following way :

**trip-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject, AngularFireAction } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
declare var firebase: any;
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';



@Injectable()
export class TripDataService {

finalItems:any;
public data: Array<any> =[];
public myData: any[] =[];

constructor(db : AngularFireDatabase) {       
 this.finalItems = db.object('/').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
  return [ ...action.payload.val() ];
});
}
}
```

**my component file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TripDataService } from '../trip-data.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-comp-firebasr',
  templateUrl: './list-comp-firebasr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-comp-firebasr.component.css'],
  providers: [TripDataService]
})
export class ListCompFirebasrComponent implements OnInit {
trip_details;
responseArray;

  constructor(service: TripDataService) {
    service.finalItems.subscribe(item => {
            this.trip_details= item.filter(function(obj){
                return obj.trip_type == "Requested";
            });    
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And finally my **html file :**

```
<div>
   <h4>Requested Trips</h4>
     <ul *ngFor="let trip of trip_detials">
       <li>
       {{ trip.destination }}
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```